# Почему transform: translate(-50%, -50%) размывает текст?

Tags: html, css, transform

Много где я использую эту фичу, ибо удобно:

```
@include transform(translate(-50%, -50%));
          left: 50%;
          top: 50%;
```

но появилась проблема со шрифтами, они становятся размытыми

вот С этим стилем:

[image: вот С этим стилем]

вот БЕЗ этого стиля:

[image: вот БЕЗ этого стиля]

Пробовал давать `translateZ(0)` -не помогло

Что можете посоветовать?
Спасибо

Comment: Вам может помочь это: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2014/05/04/fixing-typography-inside-of-2-d-css-transforms/
Переводить на полноценный ответ мне лень)

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Ну, я гляну, но беглым взглядом окинув я понял, что все это я уже пробовал

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка опасная статья - про IE хорошие вещи пишут ;)

Answer (score 5):

Есть один метод, случайно дошел сам, когда столкнулся с той же проблемой.

**Рецепт:**
Добавить больший `z-index` анимируемому элементу и меньший `z-index` не анимируемому в данном случае блоку с текстом.

**В чем соль?**

Соль в том, что когда у нас есть анимация/переход/трансформация, то она действует на все слои (позиционированную html-разметку). Чтобы этого избежать нужно указать на какой слой будет воздействие, в этом нам поможет z-index. Когда мы прописываем больший z-index анимации, мы говорим что нам нужны изменения со слоя n и выше. Т.е слои которые находятся под анимируемым затронуты анимацией/переходом/трансформацией не будут (Попробуйте сделать наоборот и работать ничего не будет).

P.S Читал пару статей в интернете про аппаратное ускорение. Кстати там говорилось о композитных слоях, но про z-index сказано не было. Но видать это очень важная вещь как оказывается.

Answer (score 2):

Тоже искал решение этого вопроса, методом тыка выяснил, помогло свойство line-height: 1;

Comment: помогло свойство line-height: 1

Answer (score 1):

Тоже задался вопросом (пока искал, заметил этот же баг на это сайте при регистрации, когда всплывает окно для загрузки картинки профиля) и нашел причину: это единицы измерения. Видимо, браузер располагает блок автоматом, например, на 120.5px, и из-за этого не может нормально прорисовать. Для проверки добавлял 1px высоты блоку вручную - всё идеально. Добавляешь 2px - снова размывается, и т.д. В Мозилле всё отлично, а вот хром такую фигню выдает. Остается только скриптом проверять высоту блока или что-то подобное использовать: transform: translate(0,-50.1%);
Попробовал вот такое решение JQ на одном сайте, вроде работает:

```
var newht=$('.modalBlock').height();
newht=($(window).height()-newht)/2;
if(newht%1!=0){
$('.modalBlock').height($('.modalBlock').height()+1);
}
```

При каждой отрисовке модального окна предварительно высоту обновлять тоже через JS (если вдруг высота блока меняется и модалки разные):

```
$('.modalBlock').css('height','auto');
```

Либо, на чистом JS аналогичное делать, кому как удобнее.

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае размытость возникала из-за `border: 1px;` в блоке.